# Reshape a Panda Pivoted Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have the dataframe in the snippet below (don't know how to past such an amount of data differently, sorry):

```html
<style type="text/css">
    table.tableizer-table {
        font-size: 12px;
        border: 1px solid #CCC; 
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    } 
    .tableizer-table td {
        padding: 4px;
        margin: 3px;
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
    }
    .tableizer-table th {
        background-color: #104E8B; 
        color: #FFF;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
<table class="tableizer-table">
<thead><tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th><</th><th>Presentation deceptionScore</th><th>...</th><th>Presentation score</th></tr></thead><tbody>
 <tr><td>companyIdFromProvider</td><td>000BFD-E</td><td>000BFS-E</td><td>000BFT-E</td><td>000BG2-E</td><td>000BG4-E</td><td>000BG7-E</td><td>000BGB-E</td><td>000BGD-E</td><td>000BH1-E</td><td>000BHL-E</td><td>...</td><td>0MJFM3-E</td><td>0MJHR2-E</td><td>0MJHRX-E</td><td>0MJPDF-E</td><td>0MJW7R-E</td><td>0MJW97-E</td><td>0MK7PS-E</td><td>0MK7QB-E</td><td>0MLWCV-E</td><td>0MM7GH-E</td></tr>
 <tr><td>publicationDate</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2020-07-18</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>2.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>...</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2020-07-19</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>2.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>...</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2020-07-20</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>2.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>...</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2020-07-21</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>2.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>...</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2020-07-22</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>2.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>...</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2020-07-23</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>2.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>...</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2020-07-24</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>2.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>...</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2020-07-25</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>2.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>...</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2020-07-26</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>2.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>...</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2020-07-27</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>2.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>...</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2020-07-28</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>2.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>...</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2020-07-29</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>2.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>...</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2020-07-30</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>2.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>...</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2020-07-31</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>2.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>...</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2020-08-01</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>2.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>...</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2020-08-02</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>2.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>...</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2020-08-03</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>2.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>...</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2020-08-04</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>2.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>...</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2020-08-05</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>2.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>...</td><td>NaN</td><td>-0.094118</td><td>NaN</td><td>0.482759</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2020-08-06</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>2.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>...</td><td>NaN</td><td>-0.094118</td><td>NaN</td><td>0.482759</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2020-08-07</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>2.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>...</td><td>NaN</td><td>-0.094118</td><td>NaN</td><td>0.482759</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>0.258065</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2020-08-08</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>2.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>...</td><td>NaN</td><td>-0.094118</td><td>NaN</td><td>0.482759</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>0.258065</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2020-08-09</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>2.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>...</td><td>NaN</td><td>-0.094118</td><td>NaN</td><td>0.482759</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>0.258065</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2020-08-10</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>2.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>...</td><td>NaN</td><td>-0.094118</td><td>NaN</td><td>0.482759</td><td>NaN</td><td>0.453125</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>0.258065</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2020-08-11</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>2.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>...</td><td>NaN</td><td>-0.094118</td><td>NaN</td><td>0.482759</td><td>NaN</td><td>0.453125</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>0.258065</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2020-08-12</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>2.0</td><td>1.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>...</td><td>NaN</td><td>-0.094118</td><td>NaN</td><td>0.482759</td><td>NaN</td><td>0.453125</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>NaN</td><td>0.258065</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

How to revert it back so that it will be like this (see below) ?

Date, CompanyIDFromProvider,Presentation Score, Presentation DeceptionScore

01-01-2020,AAPL,0.3,0.4

01-01-2020,MSFT,0.3,0.4

01-01-2020,INTC,0.3,0.4

01-02-2020,AAPL,0.3,0.4

01-02-2020,MSFT,0.3,0.4

01-02-2020,INTC,0.3,0.4

I tried with .melt but without luck.

Comment: Please share the data not as image but as text, so that one can copy paste. Thank you

Comment: copy a small section of the dataframe, run ``df.to_dict("list")`` and paste the output. It should be much easier to work with than what you currently shared